# In Embedded Sqlrpgle, Can i fetch the records who's name starts with "Y". can we do?

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

Exec Sql
  select * from filename;

Exec Sql
  Now here i want to fetch the records who's name starts with "Y" into some variable;

display the name on the screen

Comment: Table rows do not have names. Can you give us some sample data, and the result you are trying to achieve? What do you want to do with the result once you have it? Where do you want it to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not giving us much to go on, but I will guess you want to use something like:

Select * from files where filename like 'Y%';